# How to write a custom Equidistant Conic projection with standard parallels at -30 and -60 N?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm super new to QGIS, so maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but when I try to georeference the raster of a regional map that I made in an Equidistant Conic projection with certain standard parallels, I can't seem to project it into my Plate-Carree world map without severe distortion. Is there a way I can write a custom CRS for the projection I'm using for the regional map?

I am trying to project this equidistant conic regional map:

[image: regional map]

The red graticule occurs at every 30 degrees. Standard parallels are -30 and -60 N, and the longest meridian in this image is 60 E.

I am trying to project it into this equirectangular world map:

[image: equirectangular world map]

Comment: Hi! Longitude of projection center seems to be 45 degrees? So the proj string might be: `+proj=eqdc +lat_1=-60 +lat_2=-30 +lon_0=45`, and the same ellipsoid used in the equirectangular one. But that's not enough to georeference. What you need are the coordinates of the upper left and lower right corners.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thank you for your response! I'm not sure what you mean by longitude of projection center, but the Plate Carree is centered on the planet's prime meridian and the longest visible line of longitude in the regional map is 60 degrees E. Lower right corner of the regional map is -59.1 N, 112.1 E; upper left corner of the regional map is -30.5 N, 34.1 E. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a meridian that in the conical projection would look like a vertical line. Although it is not represented. Do you think that this meridian could be 45 degrees East?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Good eye! It was 45 degrees East exactly, according to the original graticule over the G.projector map I made to trace over it in Illustrator. So, what do you mean by the ellipsoid?

Comment: Does the Plate Carrée projection have any associated ellipsoid or sphere? What is the coordinate reference system of the equirectangular map?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I drew it in Illustrator. the CRS I'm using on that is ESRI:54001

Comment: Ok, it is based on WGS84 ellipsoid. Let me see if can answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to do with the command line interfaces of the [proj](https://proj.org/apps/proj.html) and [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) applications, but let's try it directly in QGIS (3.18).

Both images were downloaded directly from their source in the question, in JPG format.

---

Note that the JPG format does not have any kind of geographic reference, so both images had to be georeferenced.

To have a geographic reference as a base, I loaded the OpenStreetMap basemap layer. I set the (project) map canvas with the ESRI:54001 (World_Plate_Carree) projected CRS.

[image: 1]

Create a new point temporary scratch layer defined in the EPSG:4326 (WGS84 geographic coordinates) CRS, and draw two points representing the extremes of the equirectangular image to be georeferenced.

[image: 2]

Export the points layer to the ESRI:54001 CRS and query points coordinates with the vertex editing tool, the must show:

```
Upper Left X = -20037508.343
Upper Left Y = 10018754.171
Lower Roght X = 20037508.343
Lower Right Y = -10018754.171
```

[image: 3]

Load the equirectangular image to the map, and reference it with the Translate (Convert format) process. Important parameters are the definition of the coordinate reference system and the coordinates of the vertices (included as an additional -a_ullr parameter).

[image: 4]

I gave it a bit of transparency to verify that it was correctly referenced.

[image: 5]

---

In order to reference the conic projection image, you must create the reference system first. You can create it with the proj string (`+proj=eqdc +lat_1=-60 +lat_2=-30 +lon_0=45 +datum=WGS84`), but make sure the WKT2 string is registered at saving.

[image: 6]

The process is identical now, with the vertex editing tool, move the original points to the coordinates of the image to be referenced.

[image: 7]

Export them to the custom reference system and check their coordinates:

```
Upper Left X = -1041250.411
Upper Left Y = -3444897.149
Lower Roght X = 3412783.700
Lower Right Y = -8034800.787
```

Load the conical projection image and perform the translation.

[image: 8]

---

That's it. To bring either image to another CRS, export it. This is how it looks reprojected to the map in Plate-Carrée:

[image: 9]

And this is what the map projected to the equidistant conic projection looks like:

[image: 10]